# Why stroke removed by after effects from a psd layer?

Tags: photoshop, after-effects, stroke

I have a PSD file what I've imported into AE. There are several layers, and the objects have some stroke on it (in ps right click on layer blendig options/stroke).
But in AE these strokes are invisibles.
Why are these removed and how can I avoid it?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I have to rasterize layer first(right click on layer).
Pro tipp: In AE in Project Explorer window if you select the layer you can press cmd+e to edit in photoshop. If you save it, it will be updated in AE.